# ffmpeg streamaudio video webcam raspberry pi

Tags: video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, broken-pipe

I'm using a webcam on my Rpi to record audio video. I'm using ffmpeg
and here is my command:

```
ffmpeg -y -ac 1 -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -i /dev/video1 -r 10 -s 120*120 -async 1 -strict -2 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -ar 44100 -f mpegts out.avi
```

This generates a `.avi` file with video and audio however when I try to stream using ffserver using :

```
ffmpeg -y -ac 1 -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -i /dev/video1 -r 10 -s 120*120 -async 1 -strict -2 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -ar 44100 -f mpegts http\\some_ip:someport\webcam.ffm
```

I get `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pip`

How I can fix this? Any other suggestion to stream audio video (not with Motion please).

UPDATE

here is my ffserver config file

```
    Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
#NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>
    File /tmp/feed1.ffm
    FileMaxSize 200K
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

# if you want to use mpegts format instead of flv
# then change "live.flv" to "live.ts"
# and also change "Format flv" to "Format mpegts"
<Stream live.avi>
    Format mpegts
    Feed feed1.ffm

    VideoCodec mjpeg
    VideoFrameRate 30
    VideoBitRate 512
    VideoSize 320x240
    AVOptionVideo crf 23
    AVOptionVideo preset medium
    # for more info on crf/preset options, type: x264 --help
    AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

    AudioCodec aac
    Strict -2
    AudioBitRate 128
    AudioChannels 2
    AudioSampleRate 44100
    AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
</Stream>
```

when I save the stream to a local file out.avi I can see video and audio but when I use ffserver vlc on my windows machine is not even able to display video (black screen with some sound glitches from time to time)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When pushing the source to `ffserver` you must use the `ffm` format. Either drop `-f mpegts` and make sure the URL ends in `.ffm` or replace it with `-f ffm`.

[FFserver Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver)

Comment: I have tried that, but the stream doesn't have audio stream only video

Comment: @user3291059 in that case you should post the full console output of the command and the `ffserver` configuration

Comment: please take a look at my config file